# Most number of drivers penalised prior to a race starting

Tags: formula-1

At the [2022 Italian GP at Monza](https://www.formula1.com/en/results.html/2022/races/1120/italy/starting-grid.html), 9 racing drivers (Verstappen, Perez, Ocon, Bottas, Magnussen, Schumacher, Sainz, Hamilton, Tsunoda) were issued with grid penalties, to varying degrees, altering the starting grid for the race.

**Is this the most amount of penalised drivers on a starting grid?**

For clarification, I am looking for the number of drivers penalised, not the total number of penalties applied (e.g. Tsunoda had three separate penalties applied at this race weekend).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't find a race with more grid penalties, but found another race that matched the number of penalised drivers (9):

[2017 Italian Grand-Prix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017_Italian_Grand_Prix): 9 grid penalties were awarded in total:

- Max Verstappen
- Daniel Ricciardo
- Stoffel Vandoorne
- Sergio Pérez
- Nico Hülkenberg
- Fernando Alonso
- Carlos Sainz Jr.
- Jolyon Palmer
- Romain Grosjean

So I think it's safe to say that **9 grid penalties is the maximum number of grid penalties in a single race**, especially given they have only become relevant since the [start of the turbo hybrid era in 2014](https://www.racefans.net/2022/09/15/this-shouldnt-be-part-of-the-dna-of-racing-f1-drivers-tire-of-grid-penalty-confusion/) (despite being around since 2004), so the time window within which many grid penalties could have been handed out is quite small.

An interesting record though for the driver with the most penalties is Jenson Button who got a [70-place grid penalty](https://www.carthrottle.com/post/jenson-button-just-received-a-record-70place-f1-grid-penalty-in-mexico/) at the [2015 Mexican Grand-Prix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_Mexican_Grand_Prix), back when changing each engine component gave a set amount of grid place penalties, whereas today it's just a "back of the grid" penalty for a full engine change.